# A problem of non-emptiness of intersections of certain chains of regular open sets

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, lattices, boolean-algebras

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathrm{RO}(X)$ its complete boolean algebra of regular opens. Define well inside relation: $$U\prec V\iff\overline{U}\subseteq V.$$ Let $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathrm{RO}(X)$ be a chain such that (a) any two distinct elements of $\mathcal C$ are comparable w.r.t. $\prec$ and (b) $\mathcal C$ is strictly descending, i.e. for every $U$ in the chain there is $V$ in the same chain with $V\subsetneq U$.

Of course, the intersection of $\mathcal C$ does not have to be non-empty (e.g. take $\{(n,+\infty)\mid n\in\omega\}\subseteq\mathrm{RO}(\mathbf{R})$, with $\mathbf{R}$ the set of reals), but it is always non-empty if the space is compact.

Say that a chain $\mathcal  C$ *covers* $\mathcal D$ iff for every $U\in\mathcal C$ there is $D\in\mathcal D$ such that $D\subseteq U$. Further, call $\mathcal C$  *c-minimal* if for every $\mathcal D$ covered by $\mathcal C$, $\mathcal C$ is also covered by $\mathcal D$.

My problem is whether for every non-empty c-minimal chain $\mathcal C$ (in an atomless $\mathrm{RO}(X)$) which satisfies (a) and (b), $\bigcap\mathcal C$ is non-empty.

EDIT: Changed the terminology since, as pointed in the comments, the one I used originally was a bit misleading.

Comment: Your definition of co-initial seems strange to me, since it would be that $\mathcal{C}$ is a chain converging to a much smaller intersection than $\mathcal{D}$, but this isn't usually what is meant by "co-initial". Usually, co-initial would imply that the limit is the same.

Comment: Your definition of strictly descending seems to rule out a chain with only one element.

Comment: Yes, according to my definition one of the chains may happen to converge a larger (smaller) intersection than the other. And one-element chains are excluded. By the definition and by dependent choices every such chain is infinite.

Comment: My use of coinitial is the same as this one: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/coinitial To be honest I have never encountered a different notion, but this may be my ignorance of course.

Comment: Maybe it woube more reasonable to say $\mathcal C$ covers $\mathcal D$ and reserve the coinitiality for mutual covering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a provisional negative answer.
If $\mathcal{C}$ is a c-minimal chain then $N=\bigcap\mathcal{C}$ is closed and nowhere dense (if nonempty): if the interior is nonempty take a nonempty regular open set $O$ such that $\overline{O}\subseteq \operatorname{int}N$. Then the chain $\mathcal{C}\cup\{O\}$ is covered by $\mathcal{C}$ but it does not cover it. This shows that a c-minimal chain does not have a minimum and that $\bigcap\mathcal{C}=\bigcap\{\overline{C}:C\in\mathcal{C}\}$ is closed.
Now the chain $\{C\setminus N:C\in\mathcal{C}\}$ is c-minimal in $X\setminus N$ and its intersection is empty.
This is provisional in the sense that I could not think of a c-minimal chain. For example, in the real line every chain is countable and by diagonalising a co-initial sequence one can construct a strictly smaller chain. Correction: every well-ordered (up or down) chain is countable; every chain still has a co-initial sequence.

**Added 2023-01-09:** Consider the ordinal $\omega_1$ with its order topology. It is well known that the intersection of two closed and unbounded sets is again closed and unbounded. From this we deduce that if $U$ and $V$ are open such that $U\prec V$ then either $\overline{U}$ is compact or $V$ contains an interval $[\alpha,\omega_1)$ for some $\alpha<\omega_1$. For is $\overline{U}$ is not compact then it is unbounded; the complement of $V$ is closed and disjoint from $\overline{U}$, and hence bounded.
The chain $\mathcal{C}=\bigl\{[\alpha+1,\omega_1):\alpha<\omega_1\}$ consists of clopen sets and it satisfies conditions (a) and (b). If $\mathcal{C}$ covers a chain $\mathcal{D}$ then all members of $\mathcal{D}$ are unbounded and the comment above shows that every member of $\mathcal{D}$ contains a member of $\mathcal{C}$.
Thus $\mathcal{C}$ is c-minimal and its intersection is empty.

Comment: Take the chain $\mathcal C=\{(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})\colon n\in\omega^+\}$. Then $\bigcap\mathcal C=\{0\}$, but $\{C\setminus N\colon C\in\mathcal C\}$ is not c-minimal in $X\setminus{N}$ , since it covers the chain $(-\frac{1}{n},0)$ but not vice versa. I believe that $\mathcal C$ is an example of a c-minimal chain.

Comment: It is not c-minimal, let $O=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (\frac1{2n+1},\frac1{2n})$; The chain $\{O\cap C:C\in\mathcal{C}\}$ is covered by $\mathcal{C}$ but not vice versa.

Comment: There was an error in the commenst above: the new family is not a a chain in the sense of the question. Here is a better chain: let $O_n=\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty (2^{-k}-2^{-k-n-2}, 2^{-k}+2^{-k-n-2})$; The chain $\{O_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is covered by $\mathcal{C}$ but not vice versa.

add a comment

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding between us (which is my fault). Take $\mathcal C$ as above and $\mathcal D\subseteq\mathrm{RO}(\mathbf{R})$ which satisfies (a) (b), and is covered by $\mathcal C$. Every element of $\mathcal D$ must contain 0. For if $D\in\mathcal D$ is such that $0\notin D$, there is $E\in\mathcal D$ such that $Cl E\subseteq D$, $0\notin Cl E$ and for sufficiently big $n\in\omega$, $(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\cap E=\emptyset$, a contradiction. t.b.c.

Comment: continued: So every element of $\mathcal D$ contains 0 (and is open), and so $\mathcal D$ covers $\mathcal C$, as $\mathcal C$ is a local basis at 0.  I am only interested in chains that satisfy both (a) and (b), and I think my the way I formulated the question causes ambiguity. Thus the conclusion is that $\mathcal C$ is minimal among all chains which have (a) and (b) from my question.

Comment: In your example, the sequence $(\frac{1}{2^n})$ is in every $O_n$, so $0$ is in the closure of every $O_n$, but not in $O_n$ itself. So distinct elements of $\{O_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ are not comparable w.r.t. $\prec$.

Comment: When you pick $\overline{O}\subseteq \operatorname{int}N$ do you assume (weak) regularity? I cannot see how one can do this without the assumption. Non-atomicity is not enough, as you only know that every non-empty r.o. subset of $X$ has a proper non-empty r.o. subset.

Comment: @MadHatter For this example: yes. Just to get a feeling for the problem.

Comment: The chain $\mathcal{C}\cup\{O\}$ does not satisfy condition (b) from the question since $O$ is its minimal element. If you assume weak regularity, then in the atomless case, by means of the axiom of dependent choices, it can be extended to one that meets (b). This extended chain serves your purpose since no element in the new fragment contains anything from $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: @MadHatter I added a counterexample to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I analyzed the same set, but lacked your insight :). I really like the proof, and I don't think I would have found it.